# Azure SQL Database Advisor suggestion

Tags: azure, entity-framework-6, azure-sql-database

I recently received an email (actually two) from the Azure SQL Performance Advisor service saying that my database on Azure needs an index tuning and this recommendation is given for free.

This is a very good service in my opinion, as I am not a Database expert.

However the recommendation was really strange because suggest to create an index on a database column which is already a foreign key (so it already has an index).

```
Recommended action:     CreateIndex
Indexed columns:    [Xxxxxx]
Estimated Index Impact:     HIGH IMPACT
Date:   2016-11-17
```

I need to specify that the column is actually managed through a foreign key data annotation attribute in EF6.

I have then tried to apply the recommendation so I have decorated the column with the `[Index]` attribute and I suspected, the corresponding migration only did an index rename.

However, what I am not able to do through data annotation attribute, is to specify the included column in the index.

Can this be the problem identified from the advisory service? In this case, if I create the index by using a DDL directly on the database, how o I maintain the database structure in sync with the code?

**EDIT:**

As per [@ErikEJ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/183934/erikej) comment, I am adding the DDL for the table as it is before applying the recommendation:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SVC](
    [SVCID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [....other fields omitted for brevity...],
    [CampaignID] [int] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_SVC] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [SVCID] ASC )
     WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = ON, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[SVC]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_SVC_CampaignID] FOREIGN KEY([CampaignID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[SvcCampaign] ([CampaignID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[StoredValueCard] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_SVC_CampaignID]
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_CampaignID] ON [dbo].[SVC] ( [CampaignID] ASC ) 
  WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = ON, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, 
        ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

As I already wrote, the index is already in place and if I add an Index attribute on the class member, I only get a rename of the index as a migration result. Sorry for not making it clear however.

Comment: Foreign keys do NOT have an index by default, what makes you think that Wouk be the case?

Comment: Because when I have applied the recommendation the corresponding migration only has a RenameIndex inside...

Comment: But that is code, not the database! Did you look at the database schema?

Comment: Right. But the database is correctly aligned with the code. I assumed that was implicit.

Comment: Does the table have an index on the column yes or no? Pls show us the CREATE TABLE script for the table in question....

Comment: Yes, the column has the index. Please see my edit as per your request.

Comment: Wow, you are not excellent at asking questions... You must specify any included columns in the index manually by editing the migration

Comment: Could you please specify: 1) how can I add included column in the index? 2) what is strange, or unclear, in this sentence: "[...] and as I suspected, the corresponding migration only did an index rename". I am not English mother tongue but this clearly states that an index implicitly exists on the database. I can accept that, because of my mother tongue, a question can be bad posed and so badly interpreted, but that has nothing to do with the question itself, which still has not received an answer. Or, maybe, you consider your comment an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Original respondent is correct, FKs are not indexed by default.  The database advisor will create the index for you if you just let it.

As for "maintaining the database structure", that really is all about sql scripts and unless you are maintaining a reference implementation that isn't a critical concern.

Comment: Well, it makes sense. However, there is already an index in place. I have edited my question by adding the DDL script reverse engineered from the actual database.